# Which process is the Visual Studio F# interactive window hosted by?

Tags: visual-studio, process, f#, interactive

I'm assuming that code executed in the F# interactive window in Visual Studio is hosted in the devenv process, but I'm not certain of that. There's another process called fsi that I would guess is the actual interactive process, but I'm not certain of that.

Can you clarify for me which process hosts this?

Comment: [F# Interactive (fsi.exe) can be used to write code at the console or in a window in Visual Studio.  To run F# Interactive through Visual Studio, you can click the appropriate toolbar button labeled F# Interactive, or use the keys Ctrl+Alt+F. Doing this will open the interactive window, a tool window running an F# Interactive session.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, F# interactive window basically output of fsi.exe process running separately from Visual Studio. In Visual Studio Tools/Options menu you can choose 64-bit mode for this fsi process.